# pcap_loop function is not "reactive". Why?

Tags: c, macos, unix, libpcap

Why is it that after the pcap_loop function has been called, I must wait several seconds to capture the first packets?

```
void print_packet(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pcap_t * handle;
    char dev_name[] = "en0";
    char err_buf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    handle = pcap_open_live(dev_name, 4096, 1, 0, err_buf);

    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n" , dev_name , err_buf);
        exit(1);
    }

    pcap_loop(handle, 1, print_packet, NULL);
    pcap_close(handle);

    exit(0);
}

void print_packet(u_char * args, const struct pcap_pkthdr * hdr, const u_char * buff)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: `tcpdump -i eth0` starts giving me packets immediately; I presume `tcpdump` uses `pcap_loop()`. Can you prepare a short demonstration program to show the delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem by reading `pcap_open_live` documentation:

```
pcap_t *pcap_open_live(const char *device, int snaplen, int promisc, int to_ms, char *errbuf)
```

> [...] to_ms specifies the read timeout in milliseconds.  The read
>          timeout is used to arrange that the read not necessarily return immediately when a  packet  is  seen,
>          but that it wait for some amount of time to allow more packets to arrive and to read multiple packets
>          from the OS kernel in one operation.  Not all platforms support a read  timeout;  on  platforms  that
>          don't,  the  read timeout is ignored.  A zero value for to_ms, on platforms that support a read time-
>          out, will cause a read to wait forever to allow enough packets to arrive, with no timeout. [...]

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.5/man3/pcap_open_live.3.html).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. Lately, I have had a similar problem with latency in python/pcapy